# How to create a Worker/Manager Cluster in different machines?

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing

In "http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29918203", it describe the method to create a Worker/Manager Cluster, 
but it only include 1 manager node and 1 worker node and they are in the same machine.

For ELB,
In /repository/conf/loadbalancer.conf, it sets

```
appserver {
    domains{
        wso2.as.domain {
            tenant_range *;
            group_mgt_port 4000;
            mgt {
                hosts mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com;
            }
            worker {
                hosts as.cloud-test.wso2.com;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In host, it sets
127.0.0.1 mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com
127.0.0.1 as.cloud-test.wso2.com

For manager node,
in carbon.xml,it sets

```
<HostName>as.cloud-test.wso2.com</HostName>
<MgtHostName>mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com</MgtHostName>
```

For worker node,
in carbon.xml,it sets

```
<HostName>as.cloud-test.wso2.com</HostName>
```

I want to create a cluster including 1 manager node and 2 worker nodes, and they are all in different machines.
for example
manager node in 192.168.10.10
work1 node   in 192.168.10.11
work2 node   in 192.168.10.12

Anyone knows how to modify in the above places?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining the corresponding ip addresses of your worker/manager nodes in hosts file in linux environment.

edit hosts file using following command

1.Go to root using `cd /` command

2.Then edit the hosts file using your favorite editor. I use gedit

```
gedit etc/hosts
```

1. then you have to define your hosts names and the actual IP addresses here

   **192.168.10.10 hosts mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com**

   **192.168.10.11 hosts as.cloud-test.wso2.com**

Then save the **hosts** file and deploy your setup. This will answer your issue

Comment: How to setting the hostname of work2? And how to set the IP address of work2(192.168.10.12) in file hosts?

Answer (score 0):

```
192.168.10.10 hosts mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com
192.168.10.11 hosts as1.cloud-test.wso2.com
192.168.10.12 hosts as2.cloud-test.wso2.com
```

In loadbalancer.conf

```
appserver {
  domains{
    wso2.as.domain {
        tenant_range *;
        group_mgt_port 4000;
        mgt {
            hosts mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com;
        }
        worker {
            hosts as.cloud-test.wso2.com;
        }
    }
}
```

}

In carbon.xml management

```
<HostName>as.cloud-test.wso2.com</HostName>
<MgtHostName>mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com</MgtHostName>
```

In carbon.xml for both workers

```
<HostName>as.cloud-test.wso2.com</HostName>
```

In axis2.xml management

```
<parameter name="localMemberHost">mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com</parameter>
<parameter name="localMemberPort">4001</parameter>        
<members>
            <member>
                <hostName>lb.cloud-test.wso2.com</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>
</members>
```

In axis2.xml for both workers

```
<parameter name="localMemberHost">as.cloud-test.wso2.com</parameter>
<parameter name="localMemberPort">4002</parameter>        
<members>
            <member>
                <hostName>lb.cloud-test.wso2.com</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>
</members>
```

NOTE - as.cloud-test.wso2.com is not an address of a specific node, but an abstraction for the workers cluster